# Московская, псковская... резиденция Деда Мороза с какой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Московская, псковская и т. д. резиденция Деда Мороза с какой буквы пишется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописная буква не нужна: ***м**осковская, **п**сковская резиденция.*

А в словосочетании ***Дед Мороз*** оба слова пишутся с большой буквы.